# Rendering HTML in a <div> - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

So I have the following div and what I'd like to do, is have the div render HTML if it exists inside `{{statusUpdate.text}}`.

What I've done, is wrap the usernames in the span you see below - but I'd like it to be rendered as actualy HTML, today it's just the HTML in plain text.

```
<div ng-repeat="statusUpdate in statusUpdates | orderBy:'-time'">
  <div class="actContent">{{statusUpdate.text}}</div>
</div>
```

Currently I just get this as output - see below - and this is the output in the browser

[image]

```
<div class="actContent ng-binding">hello &lt;span class='mentionedUserTag'&gt;Aref Abedi&lt;/span&gt; how are you?
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `ng-bind-html`:

```
<div ng-repeat="statusUpdate in statusUpdates | orderBy:'-time'">
  <div class="actContent" ng-bind-html="statusUpdate.text"></div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to add `ngSanitize`, which is in a different js file (`angular-sanitize.js`):

```
app.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
```

Comment: why did this situation require `sanitize`

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd Because by default, the resulting HTML content will be sanitized using the $sanitize service to remove dangerous code if present. You can read more about this in the [official page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS escapes html by default. To render the HTML you have to use `ng-bind-html` like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="statusUpdate in statusUpdates | orderBy:'-time'">
  <div class="actContent" ng-bind-html="statusUpdate.text"></div>
</div>
```

You might get an error like:
`Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.`
Use `$sce.trustAsHtml(input)` in your controller or filter to fix this.

Comment: So, I got that exact error just now. Could you point me in the right direction regarding the controller? I'm unsure how to implement.

Comment: For that, you need to add `ngSanitize` as a submodule.

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-bind-html` directive

API ref - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

```
<div class="actContent" ng-bind-html="statusUpdate.text"></div>
```

Comment: Ok great, but what would I use as the expression? ng-bind-html="expression" Thanks !